# Access data uploaded to public folder-Google Drive Objective-c

Tags: objective-c, google-drive-api

I am trying to upload pdf files on Google drive or any cloud service and read these files in my application, do I have to use SDK's or there is a way to get files from public folder without forcing the user to login?

Comment: UIDocumentMenuViewController option is there. Check about this.

Comment: @PhaniRaghu can I use it to get the data? And present them in UITableView?

Comment: Yeah. You can do that. You need to change the option for downloading / uploading.

Comment: But must and should those apps are installed in your device. Otherwise you need to use SDK's. But with SDK's you need to login into account.

Comment: Thanks @PhaniRaghu, but SDK needs authentication and the user must login to get the data or there is a way to do it without authentication?
Also the UIDocumentMenuViewController does not fit my need.

Comment: Without authentication you can't get the data.

Comment: thanks @PhaniRaghu I will test it